# Can you store facebook likes in mysql?

Tags: mysql, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am curious if you can **store facebook likes** in your own MySql database.

I did a search  and I didn't find anything concludent. What I want to store for example are the likes of a pic/pics from my website.
If is possible I would appreciate if you tell me how :)
Thnx in advance.
I found some code but I dont know how to modify it to make it working :)

```
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(href, widget) {
            alert('You liked the URL: ' + href);
        }
    );
```

Comment: actualy that is not an answer of my question, i use fb like button on my website for each pic to counter likes, and i want to store those likes on my database, they are not pics from facebook...

Answer (score 0):

Every LINK has an Facebook ID that you can get with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20id%20FROM%20object_url%20WHERE%20url%20%3D%20%27http%3A%2F%2Fgetqr.eu%2F%27
/* Not encoded: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url = 'http://getqr.eu/' */
/* this is SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url = 'http://getqr.eu/' */
/* getqr is my website and is for reference only */
```

Facebook replies with:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "10150312949782288"
      }
   ]
}
```

Then you can query for likes every time you want:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10150312949782288/
```

Of course you will need authenticate first.